# Pandas, are there any faster ways to update values?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, my table has over 10000000 records, and there is a column named `ID`, and I want to update column named '3rd_col' with a new value if the `ID` is in the given list.

I use `.loc` and here is my code

```
for _id in given_ids:
    df.loc[df.ID == _id, '3rd_col'] = new_value
```

But the performance of the above code is slow, how can I improve the performance of updating value?

Sorry, here I want to be more specific on my problem, different id has different values to be assigned based on a function and there are about 4 columns to be assigned.

```
for _id in given_ids:
    df.loc[df.ID == _id, '3rd_col'] = return_new_val_1(id)
    df.loc[df.ID == _id, '4rd_col'] = return_new_val_2(id)
    df.loc[df.ID == _id, '5rd_col'] = return_new_val_3(id)
    df.loc[df.ID == _id, '6rd_col'] = return_new_val_4(id)
```

Comment: `df.loc[given_ids, '3rd_col'] = new_value`? (if ID is the index.)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, thanks, seting `ID` as the index is about 4 times faster!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create `dictionary` first and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
#sample function
def return_new_val(x):
    return x * 3

given_ids = list('abc')

d = {_id: return_new_val(_id) for _id in given_ids}
print (d)
{'a': 'aaa', 'c': 'ccc', 'b': 'bbb'}

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abdefc'),
                   'M':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})


df['3rd_col'] = df['ID'].replace(d)
print (df)

  ID  M 3rd_col
0  a  4     aaa
1  b  5     bbb
2  d  4       d
3  e  5       e
4  f  5       f
5  c  4     ccc
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), but then get `NaN`s for no match:

```
df['3rd_col'] = df['ID'].map(d)
print (df)

  ID  M 3rd_col
0  a  4     aaa
1  b  5     bbb
2  d  4     NaN
3  e  5     NaN
4  f  5     NaN
5  c  4     ccc
```

EDIT:

If need append data by multiple functions first create new `DataFrame` and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
def return_new_val1(x):
    return x * 2

def return_new_val2(x):
    return x * 3


given_ids = list('abc')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':given_ids})
df2['3rd_col'] = df2['ID'].map(return_new_val1)
df2['4rd_col'] = df2['ID'].map(return_new_val2)
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
print (df2)
   3rd_col 4rd_col
ID                
a       aa     aaa
b       bb     bbb
c       cc     ccc
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':list('abdefc'),
                   'M':[4,5,4,5,5,4]})

df = df.join(df2, on='ID')
print (df)
  ID  M 3rd_col 4rd_col
0  a  4      aa     aaa
1  b  5      bb     bbb
2  d  4     NaN     NaN
3  e  5     NaN     NaN
4  f  5     NaN     NaN
5  c  4      cc     ccc

#bur replace NaNs by values in `ID`
cols = ['3rd_col','4rd_col']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].isnull(), df['ID'], axis=0)
print (df)
  ID  M 3rd_col 4rd_col
0  a  4      aa     aaa
1  b  5      bb     bbb
2  d  4       d       d
3  e  5       e       e
4  f  5       f       f
5  c  4      cc     ccc
```

Comment: It's much faster now, around 4 times faster.

Comment: Hi, sorry I forgot to add another detailed information about my question, and there are 4 columns to be assigned a new value.

Comment: What about `df = df.set_index('ID').rename(d).reset_index()` ? If need replace I think.

Comment: There are 4 different functions for return values?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: OK, I have idea. What is size `given_ids` ?

Comment: the size is around 10000

Comment: And need `replace` or `map` ?

Comment: Answer was modified, but not sure if merge solution is faster or 4 times repeat first solution ;) I think it depends of data mainly.